# How to extract PDF files inside many MSG files in a folder?

Tags: outlook

I have many outlook MSG files in a folder and inside the msg file there are PDF files attached. Is there any way to extract all the pdf files all at once so I don't have to individually open each one?

Answer (score 1):

Loop through all files in the folder, for each file call `Application.Session.OpenSharedItem`. For the returned `MailItem` object, loop through the attachments (`MailItem.Attachments` collection) and call `Attachmeent.SaveAsFile` for the attachments you want to save.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. You are welcome to show your existing code to let other people point to problems. But nobody will write the code for you, sorry.

Comment: If you search for "Outlook VBA: Open MSG file" you will find code that loops opening MSG files.  You will then need to search for code that extracts attachments.  Put those together and you have a routine that should achieve what you seek.  Come back with faulty code if it does not work correctly.